# PHP Error Captcha is invalid

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have pointed to my free domain `www.mysite.tk`  to my hosting  where is is physically located my site:
`www.mysite.club/index.html`

why?

I would save on domains and hosting on.
Domains are free and the inside of the hosting I created multiple folders for each customer and each has its own small page with index.html.

These pages have a `mail.php` with the verification code `CAPTCHA`.
If I make a registration from: `www.mysite.club/index` everything works fine. Emails coming !

But if I do it: `www.mysite.tk` i get an error:  `Error! Captcha is invalid`!

I am not an expert in php and html ... but I hope all you can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, Your captcha is likely using domain only cookies/sessions.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.
What can be the solution since they are not an expert ...?

Comment: Consult your hosting provider

Comment: ok.  i get it !
thx so much !

Comment: what I have to ask exactly at my hosting service?
my question may seem trivial ... 
but I have no experience in the field.
Thank you so much

Comment: Try with the same question...

Comment: Guys !
I think that is not the hosting.
I tested with Mozilla and OPERA .... it was OK.
IE and CHROME gives me this error ....
any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: We don't even know which captcha you are using, we can't begin to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your captcha is likely using domain only cookies/sessions.

The quickest solution would be to contact your hosting provider.